# Composite glare overlayed by alpha transparency of other material?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]I know the discription is a bit weird, but hear me out: Look at the image. I put a glare filter on the 2 red eyes, but it doesn't shine through the part of the shiny triangle that's supposed to be transparent. How can I fix this? I hope I explained myself well enough xD[[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your compositor setup?

Comment: Sure. One moment...

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

You might want to switch the blending mode from 'add to 'screen'

[image]

### Solution 2:

Instread of a mix node you can use an 'alpha over'. to my experience this works better for more complex overlays with multiple colours. make sure you add the alpha channel to the 'alpha over' node or it won't work
(in your case you would take the alpha from one of the 'ID masks', not the alpha from the image)

[image]

Comment: The "screen" did work a bit, but the glare still did not go through it completely. Do I maybe have something to do with the material that has the alpha transparency on it?

Comment: It might require you to switch the input images depending on what should be the top layer (in this case the glare) It should work though.

Comment: Wait, the glowing of the glare does seem to go through the transparency, just not the extra light from the glare on top of the eyes... I'm a little lost actually. The other solutions didn't really work.